# Is it possible to use CallerMemberNameAttribute in f#

Tags: f#, attributes

The attribute and C# examples are noted here but it doesn't look to be possible for FSharp.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

```
// using System.Runtime.CompilerServices 
// using System.Diagnostics; 

public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
message: Something happened. 
member name: DoProcessing 
source file path: c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs 
source line number: 31
```

Is it possible to do the above in F# and if so what is the notation?

Comment: What have you tried? Almost everything that can be done in c# can be done in f#.

Comment: If you have a suggestion on what to try then please give it.

Comment: Well the attributte syntax is `[<CallerMemberName>] arg`.  Things will be complicated by the option types - but you might get a decent error message by trying this.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I have just tried `member this.CallerInfo ([<CallerMemberNameAttribute>] ?amember0:string)`. The compiler gives no error, but the value is not populated in runtime. So the question seems to be pretty valid.

Comment: @bytebuster Excellent - now we have an actual problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick search through the [compiler source code](http://github.com/fsharp/fsharp) shows that the name `CallerMemberName` does not appear anywhere in the code, so I think this feature is not supported. (You can certainly mark a parameter with the attribute, but these attributes are special - they instruct the compiler instead of being discovered and used in some way at runtime.)

**Update July 2016**: As of late June, [F# now supports](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/1114) `CallerLineNumber` and `CallerFilePath`, but `CallerMemberName` is still absent. It seems like that one in particular is more difficult to implement, unfortunately.

On a related note, F# has a [few special identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233234.aspx) that let you get the current source file name and line number, so you might be able to get similar information with `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`   and `__LINE__`
(but not from the caller as in C#).

Comment: `CallerMemberName` has since been implemented and is available in F#.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick 'n' dirty hack, which abuses `inline` to get this info:

```
module Tracing = 
    open System
    open System.Text.RegularExpressions

    let (|TraceInfo|_|) (s:string) =
        let m = Regex.Match(s, "at (?<mem>.+?) in (?<file>.+?\.[a-zA-Z]+):line (?<line>\d+)")
        if m.Success then
            Some(m.Groups.["mem"].Value, m.Groups.["file"].Value, int m.Groups.["line"].Value)
        else None

    let inline trace s =
        printfn "%s" s
        match Environment.StackTrace with
        | TraceInfo(m, f, l) ->
            printfn "  Member: %s" m
            printfn "  File  : %s" f
            printfn "  Line  : %d" l
        | _ -> ()
```

It actually does work, more or less:

[image]
[image]