# How to get the name of function argument in F#?

Tags: reflection, f#

Can I write a function which returns the name of the function given as the argument?

```
let funName f: string =
   // returns the name of f.
```

For example, if I pass `printfn` as an argument to funName, it returns "printfn".

```
> funName printfn;;
val it : string = "printfn"
```

EDIT: I wanted to write a function `doc` which returns the XML documentation associated with the given function.

```
let doc f = // returns the XML documentation of the function `f`.
```

To retrieve the summary of the function using something like [NuDoq](https://github.com/kzu/NuDoq), I wanted to know the name of the function.

Comment: What are you actually trying to acheive here - In F# with currying this can be complicated.

Comment: Perhaps something similar to [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117842/is-it-possible-to-use-callermembernameattribute-in-f)? The OP has probably seen this, but I'll add as a note (cf. Nikon the Third comment).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I cannnot imagine why you would want to do this and I do not think that there's a way to do this with reflection, but [F# Code Quotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx) might get you halfway there.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let rec funName = function
| Patterns.Call(None, methodInfo, _) -> methodInfo.Name
| Patterns.Lambda(_, expr) -> funName expr
| _ -> failwith "Unexpected input"

let foo () = 42
funName <@ foo @>       // "foo"
```

But note that certain predefined library functions have a divergent internal name.

```
funName <@ printfn @>   // "PrintFormatLine"
funName <@ id @>        // "Identity"
```

Comment: One use case I regularly encounter where I use something similar is when implementing ``INotifyPropertyChanged``. I absolutely despise having to return strings.

Comment: Another use case is code generation. Today, for example I want to create a Rust static array, which I already have in my F# code. The structs in side the array contain function pointers. Instead of typing the whole table again with Rust syntax, I just write a script but have to find the name of the functions referenced in the struct. Don't question peoples use cases ;)

Answer (score 5):

Note that as of F# 4.0, class types can automatically quote their arguments, simplifying the call site compared to [kaefer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2807130/kaefer)'s answer:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

type DocumentGetter =
    static member GetName([<ReflectedDefinition>]x:Expr<_->_>) = 
        match x with
        | DerivedPatterns.Lambdas(_, Patterns.Call(_,methodInfo,_)) ->
            methodInfo.Name

let f x y = x + y

DocumentGetter.GetName f
```