# Is it possible to get the name of a function from a reference to it stored in a struct?

Tags: f#

As you can see in the code below (my failed attempt, to get what I want along an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599456/how-to-get-the-name-of-function-argument-in-f)), I try to get the name of a function, from a reference to that function stored in a struct, which itself is stored in an array.

But I run into the error message:

> error FS3155: A quotation may not involve an assignment to or taking the address of a captured local variable

So, if this is not how I can do it, does anyone have an idea, how it can be done?

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

type DocumentGetter =
    static member GetName([<ReflectedDefinition>]x:Expr<_->_>) = 
        match x with
        | DerivedPatterns.Lambdas(_, Patterns.Call(_,methodInfo,_)) ->
            methodInfo.Name
        | _ -> "<unknown>"

type Foo = 
    struct 
        val func: int -> int
        new(f: int -> int) = { func = f }
    end

let f1 (a: int) : int = a

let lookupTable =
    [|
        Foo(f1)
    |]

let getNameOfEntry (index : int) : string =
    DocumentGetter.GetName(lookupTable.[index].func)
```

Comment: What is leading you to require reflection? Reflection is a back-door and reflection-using F# code is less safe, with renames affecting behaviour and Liskov substitution not holding.

Comment: I have a piece of code I ported by now to 4 different languages. For benchmarking purposes. The last language on my list is rust. And in rust, the syntax of that table with the strucs with the function values in it is so different that I would have to do a lot of typing... instead, I had the idea to just use my F# module and write a quick .fsx script to create the Rust syntax from the table I have already in F#.

Comment: Ah I see. So you want to use the intermediate results of the compiler. I can't help but that makes sense.

Comment: As an aside, in Julia language it works like this: ``typeof(lookupTable[1].func).name.mt.name``. Since I also have a julia version of my code, I will just generated the Rust stuff with Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can allow yourself to store an expression rather than a function object changing the code to return the name of the function is reasonably easy.

```
let hello (a: int) : int = a
let there (a: int) : int = a

open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns

type [<Struct>] Function = 
  | F of Expr

  static member Create ([<ReflectedDefinition>] x: Expr<_ -> _>) = x :> Expr |> F

let getName (F e) = 
  match e with
  | Lambdas(_, Patterns.Call(_,methodInfo,_)) -> methodInfo.Name
  | _ -> failwithf "Invalid pattern, expected Lambda(Call (...)) but found %A" e

let functions =
  [|
    Function.Create hello
    Function.Create there
  |]

let getNameOf i = functions.[i] |> getName
```

`Function.Create hello` here converts the `hello` expression into a lambda expression that `getName` can decompose and extract the name from.

Now, it's not always possible to store the expression and you might want to extract the function from the function object.

The dilemma is that because function objects are not really present in .NET F# wraps the functions in a `FSharpFunc<_, _>` object which is defined like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L1481):

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type FSharpFunc<'T,'U> = 

    /// <summary>Construct an instance of an F# first class function value </summary> 
    /// <returns>The created F# function.</returns> 
    new : unit ->  FSharpFunc<'T,'U>

    /// <summary>Invoke an F# first class function value with one argument</summary>
    /// <param name="func"></param>
    /// <returns>'U</returns>
    abstract member Invoke : func:'T -> 'U
```

It doesn't tell us how `Invoke` is implemented although in this case it is likely just a call to the functions we care about. Using a decompiler we can extract an example of what it can look like:

```
[Serializable]
internal sealed class functions@30 : FSharpFunc<int, int>
{
  // Token: 0x06000025 RID: 37 RVA: 0x000024E8 File Offset: 0x000006E8
  [CompilerGenerated]
  [DebuggerNonUserCode]
  internal functions@30()
  {
  }

  // Token: 0x06000026 RID: 38 RVA: 0x000024F0 File Offset: 0x000006F0
  public override int Invoke(int a)
  {
    return Program.hello(a);
  }
}
```

The `Invoke` methods *knows* the method it needs to invoke obviously. We can hack our way to it. This kind of code I typically wouldn't ship but if it's just something I need to get working for a test or some internal tool I would consider it.

Using the `dnlib` that is available on NuGet (same people as the ones behind the `dnSpy` decompiler) we can load the type of the function object, find the invoke method and process the instructions to find the first call instruction and from that get the `MethodInfo` of the method called. `System.Reflection` provides we all tools we need *except* parsing the IL Stream which is a pain so `dnlib` is valuable.

```
open System.Reflection
open dnlib.DotNet
open dnlib.DotNet.Emit

let hello (a: int) : int = a
let there (a: int) : int = a

type [<Struct>] Function = F of (int -> int)
let create  (f : int -> int) = F f

let getName (F d) = 
  let n   = UTF8String "Invoke"
  let t   = d.GetType ()
  // Check that the base type is FSharpFunc<_, _>
  let bt  = t.BaseType
  let ebt = typeof<FSharpFunc<_, _>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition ()
  let hasCorrectBase = bt.IsGenericType && (bt.GetGenericTypeDefinition () = ebt)
  if not hasCorrectBase then
    failwithf "Function object base type is expected to be FSharpFunc<_, _> but was %A" t.BaseType.AssemblyQualifiedName
  // Loads the Module where the type of the function object is defined
  let md  = ModuleDefMD.Load t.Module
  // Finds the type of the function object
  let td  = md.GetTypes () |> Seq.find (fun tt -> tt.AssemblyQualifiedName = t.AssemblyQualifiedName)
  // Finds the Invoke method (assuming no overloads)
  let md  = td.Methods |> Seq.find (fun mm -> mm.Name = n)
  let bd  = md.Body
  // Find the first call instruction, *likely* the call to method we are looking for the name for
  let ins = bd.Instructions |> Seq.find (fun i -> i.OpCode = OpCodes.Call)
  let op  = ins.Operand :?> MethodDef
  op.Name.ToString ()

let functions =
  [|
    create hello
    create there
  |]

let getNameOf i = functions.[i] |> getName
```

A huge drawback of the approach above is that it relies on specific class and code layout that the F# compiler team might decide to change at anytime but for code that just need to run once or for specific internal purposes it could be useful.