# F# Access inherited type's field

Tags: inheritance, f#

Given that i have a base type that is defined like this:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type HookBase(hookType: HookId, threadId: int) =
    let mutable hHook = IntPtr.Zero
    ...

    member this.SetHook() =
        // Set the hook using SetWindowsHookEx(...)
        ...
        hHook <- hhk

    member this.Unhook() =
        // Remove the hook
        hHook <- IntPtr.Zero
```

and a derived type like this:

```
type ForegroundIdleHook(thread: uint32) as this =
    inherit HookBase(HookId.WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE, int thread)

    let hookCallback nCode wParam lParam =
        ...
        CallNextHookEx((* here has to be the hook's handle *), nCode, wParam, lParam)

    ...
```

Since i don't want to have the `SetHook()` and `Unhook()` code in every
type (in the end there will be 15 hook types), i thought of using the base type. But F# does not support `protected` members, i now have the problem to get the `hHook` within the derived types and set the callback in the base type.

I thought of using the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and a predefined method to achiev this:

```
// Base type
member this.SetCallback(callback: HookProc, [<CallerMemberName>] ?name: string) =
    ...

member this.GetHHook([<CallerMemberName>] ?name: string) =
    ...

// Derived type
do
    this.SetCallback(this.Proc)

member private this.Proc = HookProc(hookCallback)
```

In case of `SetCallback` a counter could be established to ensure that there is only one invocation of the method, but that won't work for `GetHHook` because the hook could be set and unset several times during the instances' lifetime.

Additionally due to the fact that other callees also could have the same name as the desired method this way isn't foolprove nor would i like to have a public scope for these methods either.
Beside in a test of mine it seems the attribute does not work with F# because one has to provide an explicit default value for the parameter. (Am i missing something here?)

Is there a better way to get the hook's handle and set the callback and not to have a base type have said methods 15 times?

**Edit:** As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117842/is-it-possible-to-use-callermembernameattribute-in-f) the `CallerMemberName` attribute is not supported by F#, so the option using it is inapplicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need the handle for in derived types? Only for `CallNextHookEx`?

Then don't expose it at all, instead make `SetCallback` accept a function of type `IntPtr -> HookProc`:

```
// Base type
member this.SetCallback(makeCallback: IntPtr -> HookProc) = 
   let callback = makeCallback hHook
   // do whatever you're supposed to do with the callback

// Derived type 
let hookCallback handle nCode wParam lParam =
    ...
    CallNextHookEx(handle, nCode, wParam, lParam)

do this.SetCallback(fun handle -> HookProc(hookCallback handle))
```

There's must be a better design to be found rather than just copying OOP patterns, but I'm not looking forward to reading up about Hooks API to find out.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and i think it's definitely a way to go, but like you said, a more functional appraoch would be better. So i will eventually do a redesign of all components.